# App is quit after a certain time

Tags: android, performance, android-anr-dialog

My application is quit after a certain time (it is about 10seconds). I deal with following error for a long time. I can't find a remarkable log or error stack

```
08-19 18:29:31.283 26425-26431/ I/art: Thread[2,tid=26431,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb889e2a8,peer=0x22c004b8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
08-19 18:29:31.283 26425-26431/ I/art: Mutator lock exclusive owner tid: 18446744073709551615
08-19 18:29:31.383 26425-26431/ I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I controlled /data/anr/traces.txt. But there is a situtation like this.
I choose an any line as debug point in code and I am waiting. After about 10s, I am showing belowing error in logcat. After, When I open /data/anr/traces.txt file, I see this line which is chosen as debug point.

What is the problem? How can I find remarkable error? I will be crazy.

Thanks.

Note: My development phones are android 5.0.2 and 6.0.1

Comment: are you using a thread somewhere doing something weird?cause it says something about thread & loop..

Comment: With "quit" you mean ANR or just "quit" without comment? Also no exception thrown, nowhere?

Comment: @Tony I am waiting in debug mode in first line of onCreate method. This error is appeared.

Comment: try to clean build the project, re-open android studio..

Comment: @ManuToMatic it means "ANR". Yes, there is no error logcat except belowing error. when I controlled traces.txt, in main thread, I see it where I choosed line as debug point

Comment: @Tony it means "Build > Clean Project"?

Comment: yes if that doesn't work, close android studio, open it again, clean project and run, if that doesn't work..i am waiting for your answer

Comment: @Tony that didn't work.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: @Tony of course, before I awake quitting after a certain time, I wrote this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042942/android-anr-while-getting-instance-of-sslcontex

Comment: @czemblek have you tried to put breakpoints on the service and not on the onCreate of main activity?

Comment: @Tony yes I have put breakpoints on the service class. Everything is same. I see breakpoint which is in service class at the traces.txt.

Comment: @czemblek this doesn't works only in lollipop?

Comment: @Tony everything is same for android 6.0.2. If you see comments of my another question, my app was working correctly. Suddenly, after some update, it doesnt work. And, I didnt change anything on code